# Observation Space for race strategy development - Reinforcement learning

Tags: simulation, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I refrained from asking for help until now, but as my thesis' deadline creeps ever closer and I do not know anybody with experience in RL, I'm trying my luck here.

**TLDR;**

I have not found an academic/online resource which helps me understand the correct representation of the environment as an observation space. I would be very thankful for any links or for giving me a starting point of how to model the specifics of my environment in an observation space.

**Short thematic introduction**

The goal of my research is to determine the viability of RL for strategy development in motorsports. This is currently achieved by simulating (lots of!) races and calculating the resulting race time (thus end-position) of different strategic decisions (which are the timing of pit stops + amount of laps to refuel for). This demands a manual input of expected inlaps (the lap a pit stop occurs) for all participants, which implicitly limits the possible strategies by human imagination as well as the amount of possible simulations.

**Use of RL**

A trained RL agent could decide on its own when to perform a pit stop and how much fuel should be added, in order to minizime the race time and react to probabilistic events in the simulation.
The action space is discrete(4) and represents the options to continue, pit and refuel for 2,4,6 laps respectively.

**Problem**

The observation space is of POMDP nature and needs to model the agent's current race position (which I hope is enough?). How would I implement the observation space accordingly?

The training is performed using OpenAI's Gym framework, but a general explanation/link to article/publication would also be appreciated very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your observation could be just an integer which represents round or position the agent is in. This is obviously not a sufficient representation so you need to add more information.

A better observation could be the agents race position `x1`, the round the agent is in `x2` and the current fuel in the tank `x3`. All three of these can be represented by a real number. Then you can create your observation by concating these to a vector `obs = [x1, x2, x3]`.